# dexie to use filter while exporting and importing (dexie-export-import)

Tags: node.js, indexeddb, dexie

I have two tables in dexie database and I am trying to export-import only one of them with dexie-export-import.
Official dexie document says you have filter as optional parameter

```
//Optional filter allows to import/export subset of data
export interface ExportOptions {
  noTransaction?: boolean;
  numRowsPerChunk?: number;
  prettyJson?: boolean;
  filter?: (table: string, value: any, key?: any) => boolean;
  progressCallback?: (progress: ExportProgress) => boolean;
}
```

well can any one show me how to use that filter parameter...
something like

```
database.export({prettyJson: true, filter: (table: 'A', value: '', key: '') => true});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import {exportDB} from "dexie-export-import";

function exportSingleTable(db, tableName) {
  return exportDB(db, {filter: (table, value, key) => table === tableName});
}

exportSingleTable(yourDexieInstance, "yourTableNameToExport").then(blob => {
  alert("done");
  // Result is in blob
}).catch(error => {
  alert("error: " + error);
});
```

Comment: Hi additional question, how can  I filter the value and key. 

function exportSingleTable(db, tableName, theKey, theVal) {
  return exportDB(db, {filter: (table, value, key) => table === tableName && value === theVal && key === theKey});

didnt work with the filters :( 
}

Answer (score 1):

**More simplified version of answer:**

**To export**

```
const blob = await database.export({prettyJson: true, filter: (table, value, key) => table === 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME'});
```

**To import**

```
await database.import(blob, {prettyJson: true, filter: (table, value, key) => table === 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME'});
```